# Unrecognised database format(opendatabase error)

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am trying to access a ms access table from a new excel vba workbook using DAO.database/DAO.recordset.

However, i am getting "unrecognised database format" in the opendatabase("path.accdb") line.

```
Dim a As DAO.Database
Dim b As DAO.Recordset
Set a = OpenDatabase("C:\Users\Sweety\Desktop\Database2.accdb")
Sql = "SELECT Name1,Age FROM Table2 "
Sql = Sql & "WHERE City = 'Berkeley' "
Set b = a.OpenRecordset(Sql)
Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset b
```

Comment: This is probably because you selected the wrong reference. You need to refer to something like "Microsoft Office 12.0 Access database engine Object Library"

Comment: The `DAO` reference is generic, and should work with nearly any version of Access.

Answer (score 0):

The usual fix is to do a Compact and Repair on the database `C:\Users\Sweety\Desktop\Database2.accdb`. Minor corruption issues happen quite often in Access back ends, and this will fix it (usually).

Notes:

1. Check the `Conversion Errors` or `MSysCompactErrors` table afterwards to see if there were any unresolved corruption errors
2. It is good to do this periodically as it shrinks the size of Access files